# How to get the textbox values in Blazor and show it in a span in @onblur event, if multiple textboxes generated using for loop

Tags: for-loop, textbox, blazor, onblur

My requirement is I have 4 textboxes rendered using a for loop on model, when I entered a value and focus out of any text box, I need to capture the value into a variable and show it in a span before submit

```
I have tried with call a function in blur event  

        <EditForm EditContext="@EditContext">
                    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
                       @for (int j = 0; j < transactionModels.Count; j++)
                        {
                            int i = j;  
                                <input type="text" class="form-control"                                 
             @bind="transactionModels[i].Amount" @onblur="Getvalue" placeholder="Amount" />
 
                                <span>**Textboxvalue** </span>
                        }
                    </EditForm>

         @code{
                  public void Getvalue()
                    {
                     Textboxvalue= transactionModels.Amount
                    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The code below is a demo page showing how to link an array of values into a set of text boxes and have the array update.  You should be able to adapt it to your specific circumstances. (I made an assumption that amount is a number, not text).

```cs
@page "/"

<h2>Home Page</h2>
<EditForm EditContext="this.editContext">
    @foreach (var modelData in _model.data)
    {
        <div>
            <InputNumber @bind-Value="modelData.Amount"></InputNumber>
        </div>
        <div>
            Value: @modelData.Amount
        </div>
    }   
</EditForm>

@code {
    public class ModelData
    {
        public int Amount { get; set; }
    }

    public class Model
    {
        public List<ModelData> data = new List<ModelData> {
            new ModelData { Amount = 12},
            new ModelData { Amount = 10},
            new ModelData { Amount = 8},
            new ModelData { Amount = 6},
        };
    }

    private EditContext editContext;

    protected Model _model { get; set; } = new Model();

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        editContext = new EditContext(_model);
        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }

}
```

Stick with `@foreach` for these situations.  If you use `@for` you need to define a local variable for each loop.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you really need to use "onblur", which is javascript-minded, not Blazor.

Replace your `<input type="text"...` by

```
<InputText type="text" class="form-control" @bind-Value="transactionModels[i].Amount" placeholder="Amount" />
```

The span should become

```
<span>@transactionModels[i].Amount </span>
```

If `transactionModels[i].Amount` is of numeric type (what is suggested by the name, but not your choice of `type="text"`), replace `<InputText type="text"` by `<InputNumber`.

If it is a string, do not forget to remove special characters to prevent XSS.

---

Edit after 2nd comment:

In the transactionModel class, add these properties

```
private double amount;
internal double Amount
{
    get => amount;
    set
    {
        LoanRelatedPopupVisible = (value < 0);
        DepositRelatedPopup = (value > 0);
        amount = value;
    }
}

internal bool LoanRelatedPopupVisible { get; set; }
internal bool DepositRelatedPopup { get; set; }
```

To manage the visibility of the popup

```
@if (transactionModels[i].LoanRelatedPopupVisible)
{
    <div here the popup ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I used blur event because  I need to show popups based on the value entered in the textbox when the focus out of textbox, if the amount entered is negative I need to show one popup , and if positive show another popup.

Comment: These popups could also certainly be shown by Blazor. Keeping javascript and js plugin is unnatural for Blazor and is often the sign of a migration that tries to perpetuate the tools of the past. The danger of changing the DOM in js is that Blazor may lose synchronization.

Comment: But based on the value of the amount entered I have to show the Popup. For example, if the user entered (-1000) and click outside of the textbox  I need to show a Loan related popup. otherwise, if the user entered  (1000),  and click outside of the textbox, I need to show a deposit-related popup.

Comment: Please have a look to my edit of the main answer.